# Is there an efficient way to see how many edges and verticies were created in a gremlin Upsert?

Tags: gremlin

Using a query like the following

```
g.V().has('person','name','marko').
           fold().
           coalesce(unfold(),
                    addV('person').property('name','marko')).
           property('age',29)
```

Is there an efficient way to also return how many verticies were created?

I.e. 0 in the case that the marko vertex exists, 1 in the case that the marko vertex does not exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I'd go with `union()`:

```
gremlin> g.V().has('person','name','marko').
......1>   fold().
......2>   union(coalesce(unfold(),
......3>                  addV('person').property('name','marko')).
......4>         property('age',29),
......5>         count(local))
==>v[1]
==>1
gremlin> g.V().has('person','name','darko').
......1>   fold().
......2>   union(coalesce(unfold(),
......3>                  addV('person').property('name','marko')).
......4>         property('age',29),
......5>         count(local))
==>v[13]
==>0
```

It's the reverse of what you asked for in terms of 1 and 0 existence but I suppose that would be easy enough to remedy if you really needed to but it would add additional complexity to the traversal around that `count(local)` which is pretty easy to read right now as it is.

**UPDATE:** As of TinkerPop 3.6.0, the `fold()/coalesce()/unfold()` pattern has been largely [replaced by the new steps](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/upgrade/#_mergev_and_mergee) of `mergeV()` and `mergeE()` which greatly simplify the Gremlin required to do an upsert-like operation. Under 3.6.0 and newer versions, you would write: